# Souncloud soundmanager multiple playlist

Tags: soundcloud

Hi i'm using SoundCloud manager, http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ to play audio files on my website. Following their documentation over here: http://soundcloud-sm2.heroku.com/docs/application.html , i'm able to play a sound cloud playist from a set url.

Now I have multiple sets/ playlist, how can I instantiate a new sound manager class and toggle between them by hidden their elements using css.

Here is the sound manager application code( ideally I would want to create two soundmanager.Createsound())

```
        var consumer_key = "59f0360dads135bd07sdasasdadsad8acc14ae2d929",
            url = "https://soundcloud.com/artist-2/sets/owl";       

    // Resolve the given url and get the full JSON-worth of data from SoundCloud regarding the playlist and the tracks within.

    $.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=' + url + '&format=json&consumer_key=' + consumer_key + '&callback=?', function(playlist){

        // I like to fill out the player by passing some of the data from the first track.
        // In this case, you'll just want to pass the first track's title.

        $('.title').text(playlist.tracks[0].title);

        // Loop through each of the tracks

        $.each(playlist.tracks, function(index, track) {

            // Create a list item for each track and associate the track *data* with it.

            $('<li>' + track.title + '</li>').data('track', track).appendTo('.tracks');

            // * Get appropriate stream url depending on whether the playlist is private or public.
            // * If the track includes a *secret_token* add a '&' to the url, else add a '?'.
            // * Finally, append the consumer key and you'll have a working stream url.

            url = track.stream_url;

            (url.indexOf("secret_token") == -1) ? url = url + '?' : url = url + '&';

            url = url + 'consumer_key=' + consumer_key;

            // ## SoundManager2
            // **Create the sound using SoundManager2**

            soundManager.createSound({

                // Give the sound an id and the SoundCloud stream url we created above.

                id: 'track_' + track.id,
                url: url,

                // On play & resume add a *playing* class to the main player div.
                // This will be used in the stylesheet to hide/show the play/pause buttons depending on state.

                onplay: function() {

                    $('.player').addClass('playing');

                    $('.title').text(track.title);

                },
                onresume: function() {

                    $('.player').addClass('playing');

                },

                // On pause, remove the *playing* class from the main player div.

                onpause: function() {
                    $('.player').removeClass('playing');
                },

                // When a track finished, call the Next Track function. (Declared at the bottom of this file).

                onfinish: function() {
                    nextTrack();
                }

            });


        });

    });
```